# Access DataFrameGroupBy groups (for passing them to a plot)

Tags: python, pandas, plot, pandas-groupby

I did ask this question before, but I was not sure where to begin, so it got too broad. I'll try to limit myself to one issue this time.
I have a dataframe with columns from A-X, and the rows from A-Q are distinctive only when they are looked at **together**.

This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # imported pre-emptively, because I ultimately want to create a graph

with open("data.csv") as datei:
    df = pd.read_csv(datei, sep=";")
    duplicate_df = df[df.duplicated(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K',
                                     'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q'], keep=False)]
    # The .duplicated() method gave me all the duplicates, but it did not group them separately
    # so I turned to the .groupby() method:

    groups = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
                         'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q'])
```

If I pass `print(groups)`, I get `<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x000001DF846DCEC8>`, which I understand to be correct. To display the groups, I followed instructions found elsewhere on SO:

```
# I read that for-loops should not be used with DataFrame objects, but I wouldn't know how else to do this
for k, v in groups:
    print(k)
    print(v)
```

Which returns something like this:

```
(2345, 'P6', 'B37 HU', '1235349034KS', 'zwiebel', 140, 210, 120, 'W', 'G', 35, 'HRX', 'BK678', 'Jana', 'Mauer', 'Wasser', '150')
       A   B       C             D  ...     U     V    W     X
19  2345  P6  B37 HU  1235349034KS  ...  6267  25.0  MPa  0.87
20  2345  P6  B37 HU  1235349034KS  ...  6239  29.0  MPa  0.82
21  2345  P6  B37 HU  1235349034KS  ...  6198  28.0  MPa  0.80
22  2345  P6  B37 HU  1235349034KS  ...  6179  26.0  MPa  0.77
23  2345  P6  B37 HU  1235349034KS  ...  6123  20.0  MPa  0.72

[5 rows x 24 columns]
```

What I want to do is to be able to plot a line for each group (the values change per row, and are found in column 'R' and column 'X'), but I don't even know how to call/access each individual group. I tried `groups.get_group()`, but I am not sure what positional argument to use?

I am grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: i dont think i understand the question well enough. but if you want to access different groups you can just use groups["R"] or for more more than one groups[["R", "Q"]] is this what you want?

Comment: Not entirely. Multiple rows sometimes contain the same information from column A through column Q. These "duplicates" form a group, whose values differ in each row. So, in the above result, we have one group that spans rows 19-23, where all the information from column A-Q is the same (hence the group), but as you can see, column X has different values (0.87, 0.82, 0.80, etc.).
Now, bear with me: these groups shall each form one line in a graph (points on the x axis would be the values in column R, and points on the y axis would be the values in column X).

Apologies, it IS very confusing

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of plotting grouped dataframes. You either loop through the groups, as you did, and access every group singularly (in your case it would be `v`) which you can then plot. You need to understand that at every iteration of your loop `v` is nothing more than a simple dataframe with only data from one group, so it has all standard methods of pandas dataframes, including `.plot()`.

However, this way you need to overlap all the plots created in every loop iteration on the same axis, which you need to define beforehand, take care of using different colors and eventually put everything in the legend. It is possible but not smart.

What is instead easier is to unstack the results and plot the grouped object directly.

```py
data.groupby([keys]).count()[variables_to_plot].unstack().plot(ax=ax)
```

You can find many stackoverflow entries and articles on how to achieve this and why you need to do it this way, e.g. here https://scentellegher.github.io/programming/2017/07/15/pandas-groupby-multiple-columns-plot.html

Comment: This method seems very concise! Could you explain the arguments of the methods, and what the methods do? Are the [keys], in my case, the columns 'A' through 'Q'? I want my x-axis to be taken from column R (changes in each row of one group); and my y-axis to be taken from column X (changes in each row of one group). Can `.count()[variables_to_plot]` take both x-axis and y-axis values as arguments?

Comment: The important part is the `keys` part, which is your grouper. You don't necessarily need to choose the `variables_to_plot` as you can specify `x` and `y` in `plot()` directly. But it is just to avoid any problem related to different column types... IN practice if you don't have problems you can skip the `[variables_to_plot]` part.  So in your case it would be `data.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M','N', 'O', 'P', 'Q']).count()[['R','X']].unstack().plot(x='R', y='X')`.

Comment: Huh... When I execute the code as you wrote it, it throws a `ValueError: x must be a label or position`. Just for the heck of it, I changed it to `...plot(y='X')`, and with that, I get something that looks very weird. :D